# Electronically, should single or several ground pins be used?

Tags: arduino-pro-mini

I have heard two theories of grounding: pretty much ground a board at single point, or ground everything in sight.

With the Mini Pro, is it better to provide one source of ground through the Gnd pin next to the Vraw pin, or ground with multiple Gnd pins on the board?

Comment: All GND pins on the Arduino board are interconnected, so it doesn't matter which one you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are times when you want a single ground point (*star* grounding), separate grounds with filters (separate analog and digital grounds, for instance), or you just don't care (99% of the time).

Regardless, this is usually a concern when you are laying out a circuit on a PCB. When you already have a PCB the grounds become a moot point because the PCB dictates how they operate.

For a module like an Arduino, unless otherwise stated, all grounds are equal and can be used for whatever whenever.